# Custom layout who's size is screen size

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a custom layout that it automatically sets it's dimensions, height and width, according to the screen resolution. The reason I'm looking for such a behavior is that I want to add few of these custom layouts inside a HorizontalScrollView so that each layout can fit perfectly inside the screen.

How can I approach getting and setting the proper dimensions on the custom layout view?

Thanks!

-Jona

Comment: Take a look at this first: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override [onSizeChanged](http://bit.ly/gyDUCF) in your custom `View`:

```
@Override 
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {
  //do some calculations with width and height
}
```